# How to tell if elements are equidistant in CSS?

Tags: html, css

im learning CSS and to practice my positioning skills, I need to align an entity created in CSS. Its basically the android robot. The problem is that Im not sure if I have perfectly aligned some of the elements. For example, I want to make sure that the distance between the left side of the head and the left eye are the same distance between the right side of the head and the right eye. How can I make sure?

Heres the link to the html and css code.

https://codepen.io/crismanrique/pen/QWbZxdQ

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.robots {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.head,
.left_arm,
.torso,
.right_arm,
.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  background-color: #5f93e8;
}

.head {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.eyes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.head:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.upper_body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

.left_arm,
.right_arm {
  width: 40px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.left_arm {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right_arm {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.torso {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.lower_body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* This is another useful property. Hmm what do you think it does?*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
}

.left_leg {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.left_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.right_leg {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.right_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(340deg);
}

.left_eye,
.right_eye {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.left_eye {
  /* These properties are new and you haven't encountered
 in this course. Check out CSS Tricks to see what it does! */
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.right_eye {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Robot Friend</h1>
<div class="robots">
  <div class="android">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eyes">
        <div class="left_eye"></div>
        <div class="right_eye"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_body">
      <div class="left_arm"></div>
      <div class="torso"></div>
      <div class="right_arm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower_body">
      <div class="left_leg"></div>
      <div class="right_leg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post your CSS _in the question_ as well. That link will grow stale

Comment: Sorry about that, just posted the CSS

Comment: Easiest way is to use Chrome Developer Tools. Can be very helpful in such cases.

Comment: @dumbcoder7 Can you elaborate? What should I be looking at in the dev tools? I was looking at the box model for both eyes, but it didn't make sense to me how to check if they were perfectly aligned. I tried doing ```right: 40px;``` for the right eye since the left eye has a ```left: 40px``` but that just pushed the right eye too far into the head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put borders or outlines (they dont change the size of the elements) on each element so you have visual help

```
* {
     outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can also measure the distances, ruler plugins can help [GridRuler chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grid-ruler/joadogiaiabhmggdifljlpkclnpfncmj) [PageRuler chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler-redux/giejhjebcalaheckengmchjekofhhmal)

And sure you can use the developer tools of your browser to compare the elements

[image: chrome dev tools in action]

Ah and at least, plan well so you do not have to measure ;)

Comment: Hey, i just got the extension but it doesnt seem to work for me ;(. Im clicking the extension but nothing happens :/. EDIT: just got it to work. Had to clear cache. Thanks for telling me about this extension!

Comment: Hm, on top and left of your browser tab, a ruler should appear, than you can click there and position lines, similar like in graphic tools. There are other ruler extensions but i prefered the linked one. An other nice ruler is now in my answer https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler-redux/giejhjebcalaheckengmchjekofhhmal